# How to convert "0 days 00:39:00" to only 39 in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in the following format:

[image]

I want to convert the following format to only minutes.
If it is "1 day 01:45:23", then the output should be like:
1545 minutes.

Request someone to help me out.

Comment: So need convert values to minutes like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35368639/converts-from-timedelta-into-minutes) ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55229256/python-getting-hour-from-from-timestamp/55229984) help you?

Comment: Marte I don't want to strip the time but want to convert the whole time into minutes.